# Why GNU GAWK 3.1.5 on Solaris 5.10 does not match the pattern?

Tags: bash, awk, sftp, solaris

I am parsing the SFTP 'ls -l' output via awk, to print only the results for the existing directories (yes I know that Python is better and parsing of ls is not good idea, tech limitations of task). Here is the output that I receive:

```
bash-3.2$ sftp my-server < batch_ls.sftp | gawk 'BEGIN{d=-1;wd=1}/^sftp> c/{d++;wd=0}/Coul/{wd=1}wd==0{print $0,d,wd}'

Connecting to my-server...
sftp> cd /ik/sftp_source/alpha 0 0
sftp> ls -l 0 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 65740    102          4096 Mar 21 05:15 . 0 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 65740    102          4096 Mar 21 04:21 .. 0 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            35 Mar 21 05:15 0452984832A8.234 0 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            34 Mar 21 05:15 0989855744A8.234 0 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            35 Mar 21 05:15 1258291200A8.234 0 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            34 Mar 21 05:15 1862270976A8.234 0 0
sftp> cd /ik/sftp_source/belta 1 0
Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory
sftp> ls -l 1 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 65740    102          4096 Mar 21 05:15 . 1 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 65740    102          4096 Mar 21 04:21 .. 1 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            35 Mar 21 05:15 0452984832A8.234 1 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            34 Mar 21 05:15 0989855744A8.234 1 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            35 Mar 21 05:15 1258291200A8.234 1 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            34 Mar 21 05:15 1862270976A8.234 1 0
sftp> cd /ik/sftp_source/delta 2 0
sftp> ls -l 2 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 65740    102          4096 Mar 21 05:15 . 2 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 65740    102          4096 Mar 21 04:21 .. 2 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            34 Mar 21 05:15 0335544320A8.234 2 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            35 Mar 21 05:15 0419430400A8.234 2 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            35 Mar 21 05:15 1073741824A8.234 2 0
-rw-r--r--    1 65740    102            34 Mar 21 05:15 1392508928A8.234 2 0
```

Here:

- **d** is directory counter
- **wd** is a flag, to know wether we are processing the output of the correct directory or we failed to 'cd' the neede one and we are still inthe previous one.

It looks like it does not catch the 'Couldn't' part of the string. Could anyone help me to come up with a better solution and explain why does this happen? Thanks a lot!

**PS** Note, that "Couldn't canonicalise..." line does not have d and wd values at the end appended.

Comment: Those lines are probably going to stderr instead of stdout. When running the command you use you are probably redirecting the output to process it, try adding `2>&1` if you want to process both in just one pipe.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it and thus close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part of the command after the pipe cannot see those lines because you are redirecting `stdout` but `sftp` is sending the errors to `stderr`.

If you want to redirect both of them to `gawk`, you should add `2>&1` to your command:

```
bash-3.2$ sftp my-server < batch_ls.sftp 2>&1 | gawk 'BEGIN{d=-1;wd=1}/^sftp> c/{d++;wd=0}/Coul/{wd=1}wd==0{print $0,d,wd}'
```